# Is it possible to edit the web pages in the Profile Manager (OSX Lion Server) user portal?

Tags: osx-lion, mac-osx-server

When setting up Profile Manager in Lion Server, there are a few web pages that are generated for web management of both devices and profiles.  Is it possible to edit these pages in any way?  I am just looking to customize the look and feel without changing the functionality.

If editing is possible, where are these pages stored?  I have looked through the /Library/Server/ProfileManager and /Library/Server/Web folders without any luck.

[image: enrollment page]

This is one particular page I would like to edit. Ideally I would like to be able to edit the HTML directly.  I am looking to match the page's style with a variety of other pages hosted on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to locate the source for these pages.  The root directory for the app is `/usr/share/devicemgr/`.  The portal is actually a Ruby on Rails app, so there is no direct HTML to edit.  However, there are CSS files that can be edited to fit your needs.  The CSS files relating to the page I posted are located in `/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/public/start_ota/`.